# Error en programa de encontrar pareja y capa de un entero en un árbol binario de pares de enteros

Tags: c++, recursión, árboles-binarios

resulta que tengo que hacer un programa donde leyendo una entrada de diversos pares de enteros que me los coloca en un árbol con la función read_bintree_parint() y dada una entrada de naturales, me imprima el natural introducido, el segundo entero dentro de la pareja del primero (si no existe un -1) y en qué capa del árbol está siendo la raíz la capa 0.

Me da el siguiente error: `program.exe: BinTree.hh:71: const T& BinTree<T>::value() const [with T = ParInt]: Assertion` not empty()' failed.`

Adjunto el código:

```
#include "BinTreeIOParInt.hh"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void buscar(int n, int nivell, bool &found, const BinTree<ParInt>& a) {
    if (a.value().primer() == n) {
        cout << n << ' ' << a.value().segon() << ' ' << nivell << endl;
        found = true;
    }
    buscar(n, nivell + 1, a.left());
    buscar(n, nivell + 1, a.right());
}

int main() {
    BinTree<ParInt> a;
    int n, nivell;
    nivell = 0;
    read_bintree_parint(a);
    while (cin >> n) {
        bool found = false;
        buscar(n, nivell, found, a);
        if (!found) cout << -1;
    }
}
```

Adjunto BinTree.hh

```
#ifndef BINTREE_HH
#define BINTREE_HH

#include <cassert>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

// A BinTree<T> implements binary trees with values of type T.
template <typename T> class BinTree {

    struct Node {
        T x;
        shared_ptr<Node> left;
        shared_ptr<Node> right;

        Node (const T& x, shared_ptr<Node> left, shared_ptr<Node> right)
        :   x(x), left(left), right(right)
        {   }

    };

    // A tree only holds a node pointer.
    shared_ptr<Node> p;

    // Constructs a tree from a node pointer.
    BinTree (shared_ptr<Node> p)
    :   p(p)
    {   }

    // Notes:
    //   - default operator=() is good.
    //   - default destructor is good. Θ(n) where n is the number of nodes in the tree.
    //   - std::swap() already works by default.

public:

    // Constructs an empty tree. Θ(1).
    BinTree ()
    :   p(nullptr)
    {   }

    // Constructs a tree with a value x and no subtrees. Θ(1).
    BinTree (const T& x) {
        p = make_shared<Node>(x, nullptr, nullptr);
    }

    // Constructs a tree with a value x and two subtrees left and right. Θ(1).
    BinTree (const T& x, const BinTree& left, const BinTree& right) {
        p = make_shared<Node>(x, left.p, right.p);
    }

    // Tells if this tree is empty. Θ(1).
    bool empty () const {
        return not p;
    }

    // Returns the left subtree of this tree (cannot be empty). Θ(1).
    BinTree left () const {
        assert(not empty());
        return BinTree(p->left);
    }

    // Returns the right subtree of this tree (cannot be empty). Θ(1).
    BinTree right () const {
        assert(not empty());
        return BinTree(p->right);
    }

    // Returns the value of this tree (cannot be empty). Θ(1).
    const T& value () const { 
        assert(not empty()); //línea 71 del error
        return p->x;
    }
};

#endif
```

Comment: Añade lo que haya en la línea 71 del archivo BinTree.hh

Comment: Es en la función del final. He puesto un comentario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El *error* ocurre porque la condición del `assert`, `not empty()` es falso.

Las funciones que lanzan un error cuando la condición no se cumple son `value`, `left` y `right`.

Así que verificar que la condición sea verdadera antes de llamarlas.

Quedaría así:

```
void buscar(int n, int nivell, bool &found, const BinTree<ParInt>& a) {
    if (a.empty())
        return;

    if (a.value().primer() == n) {
        cout << n << ' ' << a.value().segon() << ' ' << nivell << endl;
        found = true;
    }
    buscar(n, nivell + 1, a.left());
    buscar(n, nivell + 1, a.right());
}
```